# Retrieving event javascript facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get a list of events and a User list should contain the events that created the User and was invited. After that I'm already logged in with the User of facebook on my site I tried to grab the code below, but returned empty. Thanks for the help. :)

```
FB.api('/me/events', function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: You need to gather the "user_events" permission with you app, otherwise it's not working.

Comment: I have permission user_events and friends_events, but still not working.

Comment: Please clarify your question, one cannot really get what you want to achieve ("get a list of events and a User list should contain the events that created the User and was invited"). Can you rephrase?

Comment: on your facebook, for example, you have events that you created and you've been invited. I want to get this list.